# Rollup Total Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apex-code

I have created a table using HTML. The table consists of a header and then many rows called Family. Each Family row can have many rows representing individual member of the family (see code below).

```
<table width ="100%" class="gridtable">
     <tr>
         <th>Family Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Age Total</th>
    </tr>
     <apex:repeat value="{!Families}" var="Families">
          <apex:repeat value="{!Families}" var="Family">
              <tr>
                <td>{!Family.familyName__c}</td>
                <td>{!Family.address__c</td>
                <td>
                    <div id="{!Family.id}">
                          <apex:outputText id="RollUp" value="{0,number,#,###,###,###,###,##0.00}">
                                <apex:param value="{!Family.AgeTotal}"/>
                          </apex:outputText>
                     </div>
               </td>
           </tr>
               <apex:repeat value="{!Family.member}" var="line">
                    <td>{!line.firstName__c}</td>
                    <td>{!line.gender__c}</td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!line.Age}" onchange="rollupSummary('{!Family.id }');">> </apex:inputField>
```

My question, is it possible use jquery to update Family.AgeTotal field? Below is the JQuery I have started working on but I kind of got stuck? Any chance for any guidance?

```
function rollupSummary(familyId)
{
     //$j('#'+familyId)
     //$j('#'+'001b000000OQirKAAT').children('span').text('xxx');
     var v = $j('#'+familyId).children('span').val();
     var c = $j('#child'+familyId).children('span').val();
     $j('#'+familyId).children('span').text(v)
 }

Typical Table:
Family Name         Address               Age Total
Smith           17 Smith Street              20
      James                    Male       17
        Sam                    Female      3
Been            17 Been Street               23
        Bob                    Male       17
        Tom                    Female      6
```

So if I change input value for Smith Family, only the total age for Smith should be updated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not really sure I understand your structure, since there were no specific data in the table, but with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/zALKd/), I've made the assumption that you will have specific ages in specific fields that are identifiable, and you, for some reason, want the sum of the ages.

JS

```
$('#buttonid').click(function(){
    var personage = 0;
    var newage = 0;
    $('table tr td.age').each(function(){
          newage = +$(this).html(); 
          personage = personage + newage;
                                         });
    $('.totalage').append(personage);
});
```

### But then again, I might be all washed up.

EDIT:

Ok, based on your table, I'll give this a shot, you'll need an .each for each family name, then an .each for each age. And it might be easier if you have the td for family name a class and also for the ages td.

```
var personage = 0;
var newage = 0;
$('table tr td.familyname').each(function(){
                                            $('table tr td.familyname td.age).each(function(){
                                                             newage = +$(this).html(); 
                                                          personage = personage + newage;
                                                                                              });
                                          $('table tr td.familyname td.totalage').append(personage);

                                             });
```

Let me play with my fiddle a bit and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback Tim. I have added more information on my original question. I tried using the Fiddle but I seem to get null pointer error when i tried using it in code. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will work with the above solution and see how I get on.

Comment: I've been flogging all day and just couldn't get all the jquery selectors to work on the table. BUT! It works very nicely with divs - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/VbzmX/1/ - If you have the flexibility, you might be something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around with the response you gave me I found a nice solution.

```
JavaScript Code
        function rollupSummary(val)
        {
            var rolled = 0.00;
            $j('.child_'+val).each(function() {
                rolled = rolled + parseFloat($j(this).val());
            });
            $j('.'+val).text(rolled.toFixed(2));
        }
```

HTML Code

```
<table width ="100%" class="gridtable">
     <tr>
         <th>Family Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Age Total</th>
    </tr>
     <apex:repeat value="{!Families}" var="Families">
          <apex:repeat value="{!Families}" var="Family">
              <tr>
                <td>{!Family.familyName__c}</td>
                <td>{!Family.address__c</td>
                <td>
                   <apex:outputText styleClass="{!Family.Id}" value="{!Family.AgeTotal}"/>
               </td>
           </tr>
               <apex:repeat value="{!Family.member}" var="line">
                    <td>{!line.firstName__c}</td>
                    <td>{!line.gender__c}</td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!line.Age}" onchange="rollupSummary('{!Family.Id}');" styleClass="child_{!Family.Id}"/>
```

Hope that helps.